# How to load one to many children on onchange event?

Tags: python, xml, one-to-many, odoo

I have a selection field (many to one division field)
if I select one division need to load its' employees on the 'notebook section'.
how to implement this in openerp 7?

if i selected the relevant estate id then need to load relevant divisions.if division select then need to load relevant workers in following phase

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="bpl_work_offer_form">
<field name="name">bpl.work.offer.form</field>
<field name="model">bpl.work.offer</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<form string='bpl_work_offer' version='7.0'>
<sheet>

<group>
    <group>
        <field name='bpl_estate_id' />
        <field name='bpl_division_id' />
        <field name='user_id' />
    </group>
    <group>
        <field name='date_of_offer' />
        <field name='payment_type' />
        <field name='select_by' />
        <field name='no_of_workers' attrs="{'invisible':[('select_by','=','by_name')]}" />
        <field name='work_type' />

    </group>
</group>
<div name="Worker Selection"></div>
<separator string='Select workers' />
<notebook attrs="{'invisible':[('select_by','=','by_count')]}">
    <page string="Tea Workers" attrs="{'readonly':[('work_type','!=','tea')]}">
        <field name='selected_tea_workers_line_ids' nolabel='1'>
            <tree string='List' editable='bottom'>
                <field name='worker_id' />
                <field name='is_selected' />
            </tree>
        </field>
        <group class='oe_subtotal_footer oe_right'>
            <field name='total_workers' />
        </group>
        <br />
        <br />
    </page>
    <page string="Rubber Workers" attrs="{'readonly':[('work_type','!=','rubber')]}">
        <field name='selected_rubber_workers_line_ids' nolabel='1'>
            <tree string='List' editable='bottom'>
                <field name='worker_id' />
                <field name='is_selected' />
            </tree>
        </field>
        <group class='oe_subtotal_footer oe_right'>
            <field name='total_workers' />
        </group>
        <br />
        <br />
    </page>
    <page string="Sundry Workers" attrs="{'readonly':[('work_type','!=','sundry')]}">
        <field name='selected_sundry_workers_line_ids' nolabel='1'>
            <tree string='List' editable='bottom'>
                <field name='worker_id' />
                <field name='is_selected' />
            </tree>
        </field>
        <group class='oe_subtotal_footer oe_right'>
            <field name='total_workers' />
        </group>
        <br />
        <br />
    </page>
</notebook>
</sheet>
</form>
</field>
</record>

<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="bpl_work_offer_action">
<field name="name">bpl.work.offer.action</field>
<field name="res_model">bpl.work.offer</field>
<field name="view_type">form</field>
<field name="view_mode">form</field>
</record>
```

model code

```
class company_new_registration(osv.osv):
    _name = "bpl.company.n.registration"
    _description = "Company"
    _columns = {
                'name': fields.char('Company Name', size=128, required=True),
                'estates': fields.one2many('bpl.estate.n.registration', 'company_id', 'Estate')                                        
    }
# Bill of Material
company_new_registration()

class estate_new_registration(osv.osv):
    _name = "bpl.estate.n.registration"
    _description = "Estates"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Estate Name', size=128, required=True),
        'company_id': fields.many2one('bpl.company.n.registration', 'Company Name', select=True),
        'divisions': fields.one2many('bpl.division.n.registration', 'estate_id', 'Division')
    }

estate_new_registration()

class division_new_registration(osv.osv):
    _name = "bpl.division.n.registration"
    _description = "Divisions"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Division Name', size=128, required=True),
        'estate_id': fields.many2one('bpl.estate.n.registration', 'Estate Name', select=True),
    }

division_new_registration()
```

and needed mapping for that work offer (plantation project)

```
class bpl_work_offer(osv.osv):
    _name = "bpl.work.offer"
    _description = "BPL Work Offer"
    _columns = {
        'user_id': fields.many2one('res.users', 'User Name'),
        'date_of_offer': fields.date('Date'),
        'bpl_estate_id':fields.many2one('bpl.estate.n.registration', 'Estate', help='Estate'),
        'bpl_division_id':fields.many2one('bpl.division.n.registration', 'Division', help='Division'),
        'payment_type': fields.selection([('normal_work', 'Normal Work'), ('cash_work', 'Cash Work')], 'Payment Type'),
        'select_by': fields.selection([('by_name', 'By Names'), ('by_count', 'By Count')], 'Select  By'),
        'no_of_workers': fields.integer('No of Workers'),
        'work_type': fields.selection([('tea', 'Tea'), ('rubber', 'Rubber'), ('sundry', 'Sundry')], 'Work Type'),
        'total_workers': fields.integer('Total Workers'),
        'selected_tea_workers_line_ids': fields.one2many('bpl.selected.tea.workers.line', 'worker_id', 'Tea Workers', ondelete="cascade"),
        'selected_rubber_workers_line_ids': fields.one2many('bpl.selected.rubber.workers.line', 'worker_id', 'Rubber Workers', ondelete="cascade"),
        'selected_sundry_workers_line_ids': fields.one2many('bpl.selected.sundry.workers.line', 'worker_id', 'Sundry Workers', ondelete="cascade"),
    }

bpl_work_offer()

class selected_tea_workers_line_ids(osv.osv):
    _name = 'bpl.selected.tea.workers.line'
    _description = 'BPL Selected Tea Workers line'
    _columns = {
        'worker_id':fields.many2one('bpl.worker', 'Tea Worker', ondelete='cascade', help='Worker'),
        'is_selected': fields.boolean('Select', help="Selected or not"),
        }

selected_tea_workers_line_ids()

class selected_rubber_workers_line_ids(osv.osv):
    _name = 'bpl.selected.rubber.workers.line'
    _description = 'BPL Selected Rubber Workers line'
    _columns = {
        'worker_id':fields.many2one('bpl.worker', 'Rubber Worker', ondelete='cascade', help='Worker'),
        'is_selected': fields.boolean('Select', help="Selected or not"),
        }

selected_rubber_workers_line_ids()

class selected_sundry_workers_line_ids(osv.osv):
    _name = 'bpl.selected.sundry.workers.line'
    _description = 'BPL Selected Sundry Workers line'
    _columns = {
        'worker_id':fields.many2one('bpl.worker', 'Sundry Worker', ondelete='cascade', help='Worker'),
        'is_selected': fields.boolean('Select', help="Selected or not"),
        }

selected_sundry_workers_line_ids()
```

Comment: Please show us the code you wrote so we can help you

Comment: @furins
code added.shall i mail my whole module to you if u want.?

now model code also added

Comment: Thank you @AnneMary for the snippet, with regard to sending me the code: No, thank you, since it will not be accessible by other users so nobody will learn from your answer. Please use github, bitbucket, gist or any other service like this to make part of your code public or please try to summarize it, with just the essential parts

Comment: @furins
thanks so much for ur advice.i'm new to openerp & stackoverflow also.
little bit stuck with my project deadline.
wait 4 ur answer.thanks

Comment: @furins
as per ur suggestion i put my code in github

https://github.com/priyankahdp/openerp/tree/openerp/

Comment: I'm not confident with openerp. However, after a rapid seach online, I think you should refer to "domain" properties in order to filter your data. I'll put a bounty on this question to help you getting it solved (it takes 48 hours in order to be possible)

Comment: you are asking for loading one2many automatically when u choose a field ???

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following example to create your onchange function. This is an onchange function I have created for invoice(just an example)

```
def onchange_partner_id(self, cr, uid, ids, type, partner_id,\
        date_invoice=False, payment_term=False, partner_bank_id=False, company_id=False):
    res = super(account_invoice, self).onchange_partner_id(cr, uid, ids, type, partner_id, 
            date_invoice=date_invoice, payment_term=payment_term, partner_bank_id=partner_bank_id,
            company_id=company_id)

    invoice_lines = []
    product_ids = self.pool.get('product.product').search(cr, uid, [],limit=5)
    for p in self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr, uid, product_ids):
        invoice_lines.append((0,0,{'product_id':p.id,'name':p.name,
                          'account_id':p.categ_id.property_account_income_categ.id,
                          }))#this dict contain keys which are fields of one2many field 
    res['value']['invoice_line']=invoice_lines
    return res
```

if there is only single line to be added then
res['value'].update({
'one2many_fieldmname':[(0,0,{'field1':value1,'field2':value2,'fieldn':valuen})]
})

In the above example I am searching 5 products and these products are added in the invoiceline. So in your onchange function also you have to search the employee which comes under the division.

In your code,in the form "bpl_work_offer_form" you have add the onchange function at the field bpl_division_id.(in my example partner_id is the many2one field and invoice_line is the one2many field.)

You need to more careful when using onchange to load the one2many field. In the onchange function you have to first unlink all the records loaded in your many2one field. because if once the record is saved then if the onchange is again loaded then a new line will be created. so you need to manage it correctly.

Reference : http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/server/06_misc_on_change_tips/

Comment: Hi Anom, may you adapt your answer to the question of Anne Mary and provide some links to documentation? Thank you

Comment: i have provided a correct example. Anne Mary can test it and with little modification Anne Mary can achieve this simply.

Comment: Let's wait for Anne Mary acceptance thus. In the question there are two cascading one-to-many relationships, so the example is only partially pertinent, and this is why I asked for a more detailed answer. I placed the bounty also in order to provide help to future readers, not only Anne Mary: so it would be nice if you explain how to adapt your cut-and-pasted code and if you provide references to documentation.

Comment: hi furins, the code i have provided is an example of something that i discover after 3 days  of hardwork(before 1year). I thinks its better not to provide a example other than providing complete answer so that everyone can think on it and give a better answer. I will change the my code

Comment: still providing some references may be useful and will save three days to the next reader (e.g. to understand the parameters passed to the method, otits return values). here it is: http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/es/developer/2_6_views_events/events/events.html - however, thanks for your answer, I gave you the bounty since I believe that your example may provide hints to solve the problem

Comment: it is an old one which will not give much information. I have added the latest document reference in my answer. Please check it

Answer (score 1):

Use `(1, ID, { values })` to update one2many values

```
def on_change(self,cr,uid,ids,ur_field,context=None):
   if context is None:
      context = {}
   value_list = val = []
   if ur_field:
      ur_conditions here
      value_list = (1,ID,{Values})
      val = {'one2manyfield':value_list}
   if not ur_field:
      val = {'one2manyfield':False}
   return {'val':val}
```